# Switch off internal notebook screen permanently

Tags: display, laptop, display-settings

Is there a possibility to switch off the notebook screen permanently? The notebook is constantly connected to the TV via HDMI. However, if the notebook is left on and the TV is switched off in the meantime or the notebook boots up before the TV is switched on, the display resolution and so on changes wrong. Even if I said in the display settings, notebook screen off, HDMI on. I use MX Linux and the lid is always close. I start my notebook via WoL.

Comment: Yes, but there is obviously some inherent danger to such a strategy: If you hard-code the internal display to always be off and ever decide to unhook your HDMI display, and take your laptop elsewhere, you may find yourself with the screen off at boot. To prevent this , the better approach is to use a "detection" method through `udev` i.e. only when the HDMI screen is detected, automatically load proper settings. In order to do so could you post the output of `xrandr --verbose` when the HDMI is connected.

Comment: @BarBar1234 Hey, I don't use my notebook mobile any more so there is no problem, if the screen stay off :). But my screen names are: LVDS1 (internal Screen) - HDMI1 (TV) Is this the information you want? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn of your screen by sending it a [DPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling) command. You can use `xset` to issue such a command. Be warned! The following command will turn off your screen immediately.

```
xset dpms force off
```

`xset` is available in the package named `x11-xserver-utils` on most distributions.

Comment: Do I suspect correctly that the HDMI signal is also lost then?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you dare to try it out? :-D

Comment: you could boot a live distribution on a flash drive and try it